# Javascript: How to get 2020-05-15T05:00:00Z format date string?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a date object in javascript and I'm trying to get it to return a string in that format.

```
private convertEpochToDate(epoch: string) {
    var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
    if (!epoch) return "nodate";
    var date = new Date(0);
    let milliseconds = parseInt(epoch);
    date.setUTCMilliseconds(milliseconds);

    return date;
}
```

Instead of the date object, I need the date to be formatted in the string just like this: 2020-05-15T05:00:00Z

Comment: Use `new Date().toISOString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take [`Date#toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

Answer (score 0):

convertEpochToDate(epochTime: number), says it's mandatory. so you do not require

```
if (!epoch) return "nodate";
```

convertEpochToDate(epochTime?: number), now it's optional

```
if (!epoch) return "nodate";
```

or,

```
const epochString = !!date ? this.convertEpochToDate(date) : "no date";
```

(epochTime: number) since you are expecting date in milliseconds-which'd be a number-  eg: new Date().getTime();

```
private convertEpochToDate(epochTime: number): string => new Date(epochTime).toISOString();
```

(epochTime: Date) if you are passing as a date object. mind it's "Date", not "date".

```
 private convertEpochToDate(epochTime: Date): string => epochTime.toISOString();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check out the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library which has every kind of date functionality you would ever want.

Comment: [*When is “use jQuery” not a valid answer to a JavaScript question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335328/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)

Comment: Did I say to use jQuery? No! Moment.js doesn't require jQuery.

Comment: The point is that "*use <whatever library>*" is not a useful answer. It might be a reasonable comment.

Comment: I don't see why it isn't useful, since it could help solve the problem and very possible any future date-related issues.